# Node App crashes in Heroku - Error: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm new to Heroku and am trying to get my first Node app running in it.  The app is a basic session authentication app.  It runs fine locally but when I deploy to Heroku I get:

```
2018-08-14T14:52:34.590534+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node session.js`
2018-08-14T14:52:36.965521+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-08-14T14:52:36.939947+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-08-14T14:52:36.856913+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:549
2018-08-14T14:52:36.856932+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2018-08-14T14:52:36.856934+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-08-14T14:52:36.856935+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-08-14T14:52:36.856937+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/session.js'
2018-08-14T14:52:36.856939+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
2018-08-14T14:52:36.856940+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
2018-08-14T14:52:36.856942+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
2018-08-14T14:52:36.856943+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
2018-08-14T14:52:36.856945+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

I'm running the same version of Node and npm locally and in Heroku (though I'm not specifying engine in package.json).
Node: 8.11.3
npm: 5.6.0

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "session",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Authentication system for web portal",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Damian Duffy",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^2.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "pg": "^7.4.3",
    "sequelize": "^4.37.10"
  }
}
```

I added Procfile to initiate "web: node session.js"

My node_modules directory is being ignored by Git.

I've been trying to get this working on Heroku all day but nothing I do seems to resolve this issue.  I've deleted the app on Heroku, generated new package.json, re-tested locally, re-deployed but nothing seems to work.

Comment: The eror is in the log, it cannot find the session.js file, Error: Cannot find module '/app/session.js'.  I would start looking there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the Procfile I created for Heroku.  I had directed Heroku to start session.js instead of server.js.  Really silly mistake and only noticed it after taking a break and coming back to it.

I don't fully understand the '/app/' path that was appended onto the session.js typo.  There was no such path in my node app.  I'm guessing that Heroku returns a general '/app/' in reference to users' dynos??

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add and commit the missing file and do a push to heroku and check again?